# Unable to log in at ibmcloud CLI "Not logged in"

Tags: ibm-cloud

I need log in to IBMCloud CLI but i can't and i don't know why. I download and install IBMCloud on local and use my credentials, but throw me this:

```
C:\Users\alexs>ibmcloud login
API endpoint: https://cloud.ibm.com
Region: au-syd

Email> a.sarabia02@ufromail.cl

Password>
Authenticating...
OK

Targeted account Alex Sarabia's Account (9d39a319066846dc8c913e529b06deef)


API endpoint:   https://cloud.ibm.com
Region:         us-south
Not logged in.
```

I try with an unique access code but the same:

```
C:\Users\alexs>ibmcloud login -a https://cloud.ibm.com -u passcode -p IowCsMIeuU
API endpoint: https://cloud.ibm.com
Authenticating...
OK

Targeted account Alex Sarabia's Account (9d39a319066846dc8c913e529b06deef)


Select a region (or press enter to skip):
1. au-syd
2. in-che
3. jp-osa
4. jp-tok
5. kr-seo
6. eu-de
7. eu-gb
8. ca-tor
9. us-south
10. us-east
11. br-sao
Enter a number> 9
Targeted region us-south


API endpoint:   https://cloud.ibm.com
Region:         us-south
Not logged in.
```

How you see the only messagge that cmd throw is "not logged in"... what can I do?

Comment: Are you able to log in using the browser? What type of account? Is it limited to a region? Never share your passcodes with other because they could use it to log in, too. How does your SO username relate to the IBM Cloud user?

Comment: Additionally, if you look at the config.json file for the CLI, is it being updated with the login status? For example, in that file you should find a section that says "LoginAt" that should reflect the date and time that you logged in. On a Windows system, this will be in the \Users\<your user>\.bluemix folder by default. This should be C:\Users\alexs\.bluemix from the details you've shared.